# $ \mathbb{H}$ is division algebra of quaternions

Tags: ring-theory

Let $A$ be an algebra. For $a, b \in  A $ we define **maps $L_{a}, R_{b} : A \longrightarrow A$, called the left
multiplication map and right multiplication map**, by

$L_{a} (x) := ax, R_{b} (x) := xb$.

Note that for all $a, b \in  A, \lambda , \mu \in F ( field)  $ we have

$L_{a}b = L_{a}Lb, R_{ab} = R_{b}R_{a} $,

$L_{a}R_{b} = R_{b}L_{a}$,

$L_{\lambda a+\mu b} = \lambda L_{a} + \mu L_{b}, \quad
 R_{\lambda a+\mu b} = \lambda R_{a} + \mu R_{b}$

so , **is there an element in $M ( \mathbb{H} ) $  (  $ \mathbb{H}$ is  division algebra of quaternions )  that cannot be written as $ L_{a} R_{b}$,  $
 a, b \in  \mathbb{H} $?**